# Convert postgresql to Criteria Builder

Tags: java, jpa

I need the below query to get converted to criteria builder.

```
SELECT event0_.event_id AS event_id1_4_0_,
       emailcommu1_.email_recipient_id AS email_re1_2_1_,
       smscommuni2_.sms_recipient_id AS sms_reci1_8_2_,
       event0_.created_by AS created_2_4_0_,
       event0_.created_on AS created_3_4_0_,
       event0_.updated_by AS updated_4_4_0_,
       event0_.updated_on AS updated_5_4_0_,
       event0_.email_template_followed AS email_te6_4_0_,
       event0_.event_code AS event_co7_4_0_,
       event0_.event_module_identifier AS event_mo8_4_0_,
       event0_.event_name AS event_na9_4_0_,
       event0_.is_deleted AS is_dele10_4_0_,
       event0_.event_template_recipient AS event_t11_4_0_,
       event0_.pref_email AS pref_em12_4_0_,
       event0_.pref_hard_copy AS pref_ha13_4_0_,
       event0_.pref_letter_hard_copy AS pref_le14_4_0_,
       event0_.pref_portal_app AS pref_po15_4_0_,
       event0_.pref_sms AS pref_sm16_4_0_,
       event0_.sms_template_followed AS sms_tem17_4_0_,
       event0_.trigger_point AS trigger18_4_0_,
       emailcommu1_.created_by AS created_2_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.created_on AS created_3_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.updated_by AS updated_4_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.updated_on AS updated_5_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.event_id AS event_id8_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.is_deleted AS is_delet6_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.recipient_group_id AS recipien9_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.recipient_type_id AS recipien7_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.event_id AS event_id8_4_0__,
       emailcommu1_.email_recipient_id AS email_re1_2_0__,
       smscommuni2_.created_by AS created_2_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.created_on AS created_3_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.updated_by AS updated_4_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.updated_on AS updated_5_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.event_id AS event_id7_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.is_deleted AS is_delet6_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.recipient_group_id AS recipien8_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.event_id AS event_id7_4_1__,
       smscommuni2_.sms_recipient_id AS sms_reci1_8_1__
FROM communication.event_master event0_
  LEFT OUTER JOIN communication.email_communication_recipient emailcommu1_
               ON event0_.event_id = emailcommu1_.event_id
              AND emailcommu1_.is_deleted = 'N'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN communication.sms_communication_recipient smscommuni2_
               ON event0_.event_id = smscommuni2_.event_id
              AND smscommuni2_.is_deleted = 'N'
WHERE event0_.event_id = 51
```

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "communication.event_master")
```

public class Event extends BaseModel implements Serializable {

```
public Event() {

}

public Event(Integer eventId, String eventCode, String eventName, String eventModule, Character prefSMS,
        Character prefEmail, Character prefHardCopy, String eventTemplate) {
    super();
    this.eventId = eventId;
    this.eventCode = eventCode;
    this.eventName = eventName;
    this.eventModule = eventModule;
    this.prefSMS = prefSMS;
    this.prefEmail = prefEmail;
    this.prefHardCopy = prefHardCopy;
    this.eventTemplate = eventTemplate;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "eventid_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "eventid_generator", sequenceName = "communication.event_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "event_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer eventId;

@Column(name = "event_name")
private String eventName;

@Column(name = "event_module_identifier")
private String eventModule;

@Column(name = "event_code")
private String eventCode;

@Column(name = "trigger_point")
private String triggerPoint;

@Column(name = "event_template_recipient")
private String eventTemplate;

@Column(name = "pref_email")
private Character prefEmail;

@Column(name = "pref_hard_copy")
private Character prefHardCopy;

@Column(name = "pref_sms")
private Character prefSMS;

@Column(name = "pref_portal_app")
private Character prefPortalApp;

@Column(name = "pref_letter_hard_copy")
private Character prefLetterHardCopy;

@Column(name = "email_template_followed")
private String emailTemplateFollowed;

@Column(name = "sms_template_followed")
private String smsTemplateFollowed;

@Column(name = "is_deleted")
private Character eventStatus;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<SmsTemplateMaster> smsTemplateMaster;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<EmailTemplateMaster> emailTemplateMaster;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<SMSCommunicationRecipient> smsCommunicationRecipient;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<EmailCommunicationRecipient> emailCommunicationRecipient;
}
```

EmailCommunicationRecipient:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "communication.email_communication_recipient")
 public class EmailCommunicationRecipient extends BaseModel implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "email_recipientid_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "email_recipientid_generator", sequenceName = "communication.email_recipient_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "email_recipient_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer emailRecipientId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "recipient_group_id", referencedColumnName = "reference_data_id")
private CommunicationReferenceData recipientGroupId;

@Column(name = "recipient_type_id")
private String recipientTypeId;

@Column(name = "is_deleted")
private Character isDeleted;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
private Event event;
}
```

SMSCommunicationRecipient:

```
@Entity
 @Table(name = "communication.sms_communication_recipient")
public class SMSCommunicationRecipient extends BaseModel implements Serializable {



@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sms_recipientid_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sms_recipientid_generator", sequenceName = "communication.sms_recipient_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "sms_recipient_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer smsRecipientId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "recipient_group_id", referencedColumnName = "reference_data_id")
private CommunicationReferenceData recipientGroupId;

@Column(name = "is_deleted")
private Character isDeleted;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
private Event event;
}
```

I have created my criteria Builder as follows.

```
List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Event> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Event.class);
    Root<Event> root = criteriaQuery.from(Event.class);
    /*Join<Event, EmailCommunicationRecipient> joinEmailRecipient = root.join(Event_.emailCommunicationRecipient, JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<Event, SMSCommunicationRecipient> joinSMSRecipient = root.join(Event_.smsCommunicationRecipient, JoinType.LEFT);
    root.fetch(Event_.emailCommunicationRecipient, JoinType.LEFT);
    root.fetch(Event_.smsCommunicationRecipient, JoinType.LEFT);*/

    Join<Event, EmailCommunicationRecipient> joinEmailRecipient = (Join<Event, EmailCommunicationRecipient>) root.fetch(Event_.emailCommunicationRecipient, JoinType.LEFT);
    //Join<EmailCommunicationRecipient, CommunicationReferenceData> joinEmailRefernce = (Join<EmailCommunicationRecipient, CommunicationReferenceData>) root.fetch(EmailCommunicationRecipient_.recipientGroupId, JoinType.INNER);

    Join<Event, SMSCommunicationRecipient> joinSMSRecipient = (Join<Event, SMSCommunicationRecipient>) root.fetch(Event_.smsCommunicationRecipient, JoinType.LEFT);



    criteriaQuery.select(root);
    criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(root.get(Event_.eventId), eventId),builder.equal(joinEmailRecipient.get(EmailCommunicationRecipient_.isDeleted), CommunicationConstants.FLAG_N),
            builder.equal(joinSMSRecipient.get(SMSCommunicationRecipient_.isDeleted), CommunicationConstants.FLAG_N));

    Query query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<Event> eventList = query.getResultList();
    Event event = null;
    if (null != eventList && !eventList.isEmpty()) {
        event = eventList.get(0);
    }
```

This generates the below SQL query.

```
SELECT event0_.event_id AS event_id1_4_0_,
       emailcommu1_.email_recipient_id AS email_re1_2_1_,
       smscommuni2_.sms_recipient_id AS sms_reci1_8_2_,
       event0_.created_by AS created_2_4_0_,
       event0_.created_on AS created_3_4_0_,
       event0_.updated_by AS updated_4_4_0_,
       event0_.updated_on AS updated_5_4_0_,
       event0_.email_template_followed AS email_te6_4_0_,
       event0_.event_code AS event_co7_4_0_,
       event0_.event_module_identifier AS event_mo8_4_0_,
       event0_.event_name AS event_na9_4_0_,
       event0_.is_deleted AS is_dele10_4_0_,
       event0_.event_template_recipient AS event_t11_4_0_,
       event0_.pref_email AS pref_em12_4_0_,
       event0_.pref_hard_copy AS pref_ha13_4_0_,
       event0_.pref_letter_hard_copy AS pref_le14_4_0_,
       event0_.pref_portal_app AS pref_po15_4_0_,
       event0_.pref_sms AS pref_sm16_4_0_,
       event0_.sms_template_followed AS sms_tem17_4_0_,
       event0_.trigger_point AS trigger18_4_0_,
       emailcommu1_.created_by AS created_2_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.created_on AS created_3_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.updated_by AS updated_4_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.updated_on AS updated_5_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.event_id AS event_id8_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.is_deleted AS is_delet6_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.recipient_group_id AS recipien9_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.recipient_type_id AS recipien7_2_1_,
       emailcommu1_.event_id AS event_id8_4_0__,
       emailcommu1_.email_recipient_id AS email_re1_2_0__,
       smscommuni2_.created_by AS created_2_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.created_on AS created_3_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.updated_by AS updated_4_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.updated_on AS updated_5_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.event_id AS event_id7_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.is_deleted AS is_delet6_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.recipient_group_id AS recipien8_8_2_,
       smscommuni2_.event_id AS event_id7_4_1__,
       smscommuni2_.sms_recipient_id AS sms_reci1_8_1__
FROM communication.event_master event0_
  LEFT OUTER JOIN communication.email_communication_recipient emailcommu1_ ON event0_.event_id = emailcommu1_.event_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN communication.sms_communication_recipient smscommuni2_ ON event0_.event_id = smscommuni2_.event_id
WHERE event0_.event_id = 51
  AND emailcommu1_.is_deleted = 'N'
  AND smscommuni2_.is_deleted = 'N'
```

I need to apply the AND condition for left outer JOIN only.

How can I achieve this in criteria builder

Comment: JPQL (and Criteria) allow specification of ON, so perhaps you should specify it (Join has an `on` method). Nobody here sees your entities and those query languages uses entities

Comment: @ Billy Frost  I have pasted the entity as well

Comment: so take the `Join` that you want to add the `ON` clause to and ADD it by calling `xxxJoin.on(...)`